# ggplot2 boxplot with space respect between boxes

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I display a boxplot chart as following:

[image]

But what I would like is to have the x axis as real x axis, meaning that the space between values should be respected. Adding to this scale I would like a log scale on the x axis. How can I do this using geom_boxplot?

thanks,
Jerome

Comment: Please read (1) [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), (2) [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as (3) [how to provide a minimal reproducible example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610). Then edit and improve your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

> what I would like is to have the x axis as real x axis, meaning that
>   the space between values should be respected. Adding to this scale I
>   would like a log scale on the x axis. How can I do this using
>   geom_boxplot?

You could do

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=rep(c(1,10,50,100), each=10), y=runif(40))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, group=x)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_x_log10() + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]